# Understanding SQLite conceptually

Tags: python, sqlite, web-hosting

I looked at the sqlite.org docs, but I am new to this, so bear with me. (I have a tiny bit of experience with MySQL, and I think using it would be an overkill for what I am trying to do with my application.)

From what I understand I can initially create an SQLite db file locally on my MAC and add entrees to it using a Firefox extension. I could then store any number of tables and images (as binary). Once my site that uses this db is live, I could upload the db file to any web hosting service to any directory. In my site I could have a form that collects data and sends a request to write that data to the db file. Then, I could have an iOS app that connects to the db and reads the data. Did I get this right?

Would I be able to run a Python script that writes to SQLite? What questions should I ask a potential hosting service? (I want to leave MediaTemple, so I am looking around...)
I don't want to be limited to a Windows server, I am assuming SQLite would run on Unix? Or, does it depend on a hosting service? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could upload the db file to any web hosting service to any directory

Supposing that the service has the libraries installed to handle sqlite, and that sqlite is installed.

> Would I be able to run a Python script that writes to SQLite

Yes, well, maybe. As of Python 2.5, Python includes sqlite support as part of it's standard library.

> What questions should I ask a potential hosting service

Usually, in their technical specs they will list what databases/libraries/languages are supported. I have successfully ran Python sites w/ sqlite databases on Dreamhost.

> SQLite would run on Unix

Most *nix flavors have pre-packaged sqlite installation binaries. The hosting provider should be able to tell you this as well.

Comment: Thanks. I read the db file is read-only (locked) when it is being updated. Does it mean that the whole file is locked when user X is writing row 1 ? Or, does it mean that only row 1 is locked, but user Y can still write to row 2.